# Crystal Reports - Plot running totals against each other

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have two rows of running totals in my report.

I would like to plot these on a chart against each other with the first row of running totals as bars and the second row as a line across the top.

There are about 20 individual running totals in each row. The running totals are based off formulas fields in the detail section of the report so I can't really say as part of the Chart Criteria 'On Change of Field X'.

I just want to use the values in the running totals as is.

I'm wondering how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From past experience what I have done to get these results is calculate my running totals through my stored procedure/view enabling me to simply select them in the chart expert.

As far as I'm aware there is only two ways to achieve what you need:

1. Sum running totals manually using SQL (as mentioned before)
2. Sum running totals using a formula field.

I'm sorry it's not the answer you may have hoped for.

Comment: I dont have a problem adding the running total fields to the Show Values box (under the Data tab of the Chart expert), just like I can add formulas fields there no worries.  The problem is I am forced to select a field for 'On change of'.  I dont really want an On Change of field